# Select 2 Webpack-encore

Tags: jquery, npm, jquery-select2, symfony4

I'm trying to use select2 with webpack-encore on my symphony4 project.
My app.js file is loaded without problem but not select2 while i installed it ..
I do not understand why it's not working at all ...

**My html**

```
    <head>
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
    </head>
    <body>
    <select>
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    </select>
```

**My app.js**

```
require('../css/app.css');

const $ = require('jquery');





console.log('Hello Webpackfdsfds Encore! Edit me in assets/js/app.js');

require('select2')

$('select').select2({ width: '100%', placeholder: "Select an Option", allowClear: true })
```

**What it looks like**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdbhj.jpg

I would be grateful if you would help me

Comment: you can try something like:
 import '../../node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css'; import '../../node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js';

Comment: Thanks you for your support. I'm using twig, so i cant import anything

Comment: You can import it on your app.js, I use it.

Comment: I did it ! I have a new error message into my console

Comment: Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. select2.min.css:1:2490

Comment: Seriously, whats wrong with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply import the select2 **CSS** with a require :

```
require('../css/app.css');
const $ = require('jquery');
console.log('Hello Webpackfdsfds Encore! Edit me in assets/js/app.js');

require('select2')
require('select2/dist/css/select2.css')
$('select').select2({ width: '100%', placeholder: "Select an Option", allowClear: true })
```

It also exists custom styles, like :

- select2-bootstrap-theme
- select2-bootstrap4-theme
- select2-flat-theme
- select2-metro

You can install them with yarn.